# How to convert JSON received from a RabbitMQ Queue to CSV?

Tags: python, json, pandas, rabbitmq, pika

Currently I am consuming messages from a RabbitMQ queue within my organization. Everyday I need to push all the messages received to a csv which will eventually land up as a table in a Datawarehouse.

The code is always listening to the queue and Ideally I would want to stream the data to a csv.

```
#callback funtion on receiving messages
def onMessage(channel, method, properties, body):
    print(body)

while True:
    try:
        #connect
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username, password)
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host = server, port = port, virtual_host = vhost, credentials = credentials))


channel = connection.channel()
channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback = onMessage, queue = queueName, auto_ack = True)
        channel.start_consuming()
```

The Output I receive after I start consuming the queue is as follows: This is one row of data received. It basically returns a json object however the b'{"metrics": needs to be removed when consuming the json object.

> b'{"metrics":[{"ci_id":"SPN-EQSHATA1","client_id":"39956e6fdb256757567567433333193a","name":"deviceHealthScore","source_id":"Global","source_management_platform":"XXX","timestamp":1582886099642,"unit":"count","value":"10.0"},{"ci_id":"SPN-EQSHATA1","client_id":"39956e6fdb256757567567433333193a","name":"configAssuranceScore","source_id":"Global","source_management_platform":"XXX","timestamp":1582886099325,"unit":"count","value":"1.0"},{"ci_id":"SPN-EQSHATA1","client_id":"39956e6fdb256757567567433333193a","name":"imageAssuranceScore","source_id":"Global","source_management_platform":"XXX","timestamp":1582886099325,"unit":"count","value":"1.0"},{"ci_id":"SPN-EQSHATA1","client_id":"39956e6fdb256757567567433333193a","name":"vulnerabilityAssuranceScore","source_id":"Global","source_management_platform":"XXX","timestamp":1582886099325,"unit":"count","value":"10.0"},{"ci_id":"SPN-EQSHATA1","client_id":"39956e6fdb256757567567433333193a","name":"overallAssuranceScore","source_id":"Global","source_management_platform":"XXX","timestamp":1582886099642,"unit":"count","value":"5.5"}],"emr_published_on":1582886099642}'

Comment: what have you tried to parse the json and write to csv file and what particulat problem you have? what is the structure of the csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b'...'` just means that you got a byte string that the json module can happily process. You would get a dictionnary which, for the `metrics` key, has for value a list of dictionaries. The list can directly feed a DataFrame.

That means that you can process that as simply as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(body)['metrics'])
```